# How to get a refiner on first character of the title?

Tags: search, managed-property, index

I need to create a search index for certain search results. I'd like to have a refiner on the first character of the title. Would be nice to have a separate managed property containing this first title character!

The question has been asked before but no proper answers where given.

So, is there a method to achieve this (apart from using a content enrichment service)?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one index per SSA, so it's not about creating an index. It's about crafting a query that can return results based on the first character. Your request is the same as the queries we use for Last Name just use Title instead.

```
Title:"A*"
```

If you want sample code from a working project have a look at the [Hyperfish Company Directory](https://youtu.be/Ob6urzHiCak).